# How do I simulate a websocket disconnect manually? (Firefox or Chrome dev tools)

Tags: websocket, google-chrome-devtools, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

How do I simulate a websocket disconnect manually? I'm trying to test websocket reconnect logic, and I have no way of doing this other than waiting for the browser's 10 minute websocket timeout.

Answer (score 1):

With SockJS and Stomp:

```
socket = new SockJS(socketUrl);
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket); // global variable stompClient
```

Closing the underlying socket with:

```
socket.close();
```

triggered the stompClient's error handler as if the connection had been interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to test this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916046/2929675

Before the WebSocket connection gets opened, you must execute this script to monkey patch the browsers WebSocket function:

```
const sockets = [];
const nativeWebSocket = window.WebSocket;
window.WebSocket = function(...args){
  const socket = new nativeWebSocket(...args);
  sockets.push(socket);
  return socket;
};
```

Now you have access to all WebSocket connections via the sockets array.
And when you want to trigger a reconnect, you can call

```
sockets[0].close();
```

using the index of the connection you want to close.

It's a bit hacky, but it's the best solution I have found so far.

It looks like there is also some progress in the chromium issue to support this in the dev tools: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423246